# How to prevent an import of a module in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have set up a jupyter notebook server for multiple users to run notebooks. I want to provide modules that can fetch data and do some pre-processing. Since the data and data processing code is proprietary, I don't want the users to have access to the source code which can be done via `import inspect` module.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to prevent `inspect` module from loading? I have seen this in Quantopian notebooks where  importing `inspect` module throws an error.
2. Are there other ways to prevent access to the source code of the modules?

Comment: You can add a dummy `inspect.py` to the import path so that `import inspect` would import it and not the builtin module

Comment: That's a good idea. Thanks!

Comment: why not dump preprocessed data at the server then?

Comment: I'm actually using JupyterHub which spawns off a notebook server for every user. Adding data files to each server wouldn't ideal as data files will get large. I could put the data in a volume and mount that for every user. I'm hoping for a cleaner solution, where a user just imports a module that fetches the data. I could keep updating/ modifying the data when necessary.